# SKPOITrackerManager does not detect any POIs

Tags: android, skmaps

I have created a small Android app which should track POIs. I navigate through a route and placed 10 trackable POIs at the beginning of the route and many other trackable POIs along the whole route. As I put annotations on the trackable POIs one can see that they are created. I want to track them with `SKPOITrackerManager`. But none of these POIs are tracked.

I implemented the `SKPOITrackerListener` and `onUpdatePOIsinRadius()` is called the first two times without any POIs added. The third time it is called (~ 2 minutes after the app I starting) it adds many POIs. But `onReceivedPOIs()` does not find the POIs. It is only called once. And the `List<SKDetectedPOI>` only has size one with a detected POI having an ID equal to -1.

Here is my complete code, containing two Activites.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.michi.mapapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.skobbler.ngx.SKDeveloperKeyException;
import com.skobbler.ngx.SKMaps;
import com.skobbler.ngx.SKMapsInitSettings;
import com.skobbler.ngx.SKPrepareMapTextureListener;
import com.skobbler.ngx.SKPrepareMapTextureThread;
import com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewStyle;
import com.skobbler.ngx.navigation.SKAdvisorSettings;
import com.skobbler.ngx.util.SKLogging;
import com.skobbler.ngx.versioning.SKMapUpdateListener;
import com.skobbler.ngx.versioning.SKVersioningManager;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SKPrepareMapTextureListener{

    private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private String mapResourcesDirPath = "";

    public static final long KILO = 1024;

    public static final long MEGA = KILO * KILO;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String applicationPath = chooseStoragePath(this);
        mapResourcesDirPath = applicationPath + "/" + "SKMaps/";
        new SKPrepareMapTextureThread(this, mapResourcesDirPath, "SKMaps.zip", this).start();
        if (initializeLibrary(this)) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MapActivity.class));
        }
    }

    private boolean initializeLibrary(final Activity context) {
        SKLogging.enableLogs(true);
        SKMapsInitSettings initMapSettings = new SKMapsInitSettings();
        initMapSettings.setMapResourcesPaths(mapResourcesDirPath,
                new SKMapViewStyle(mapResourcesDirPath + "daystyle/", "daystyle.json"));
        final SKAdvisorSettings advisorSettings = initMapSettings.getAdvisorSettings();
        advisorSettings.setAdvisorConfigPath(mapResourcesDirPath +"/Advisor");
        advisorSettings.setResourcePath(mapResourcesDirPath +"/Advisor/Languages");
        advisorSettings.setLanguage(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorLanguage.LANGUAGE_DE);
        advisorSettings.setAdvisorVoice("en");
        initMapSettings.setAdvisorSettings(advisorSettings);
        try {
            SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(context, initMapSettings);
            return true;
        }catch (SKDeveloperKeyException exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static String chooseStoragePath(Context context) {
        if (getAvailableMemorySize(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath()) >= 50 * MEGA) {
            if (context != null && context.getFilesDir() != null) {
                return context.getFilesDir().getPath();
            }
        } else {
            if ((context != null) && (context.getExternalFilesDir(null) != null)) {
                if (getAvailableMemorySize(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()) >= 50 * MEGA) {
                    return context.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString();
                }
            }
        }

        SKLogging.writeLog(TAG, "There is not enough memory on any storage, but return internal memory",
                SKLogging.LOG_DEBUG);

        if (context != null && context.getFilesDir() != null) {
            return context.getFilesDir().getPath();
        } else {
            if ((context != null) && (context.getExternalFilesDir(null) != null)) {
                return context.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static long getAvailableMemorySize(String path) {
        StatFs statFs = null;
        try {
            statFs = new StatFs(path);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            SKLogging.writeLog("SplashActivity", "Exception when creating StatF ; message = " + ex,
                    SKLogging.LOG_DEBUG);
        }
        if (statFs != null) {
            Method getAvailableBytesMethod = null;
            try {
                getAvailableBytesMethod = statFs.getClass().getMethod("getAvailableBytes");
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                SKLogging.writeLog(TAG, "Exception at getAvailableMemorySize method = " + e.getMessage(),
                        SKLogging.LOG_DEBUG);
            }

            if (getAvailableBytesMethod != null) {
                try {
                    SKLogging.writeLog(TAG, "Using new API for getAvailableMemorySize method !!!", SKLogging.LOG_DEBUG);
                    return (Long) getAvailableBytesMethod.invoke(statFs);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    return (long) statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) statFs.getBlockSize();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    return (long) statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) statFs.getBlockSize();
                }
            } else {
                return (long) statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) statFs.getBlockSize();
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapTexturesPrepared(boolean b) {
        initializeLibrary(this);
    }
}
```

MapActivity:

```
package com.example.michi.mapapplication;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.skobbler.ngx.SKCoordinate;
import com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKAnimationSettings;
import com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKAnnotation;
import com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKCalloutView;
import com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKCoordinateRegion;
import com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapCustomPOI;
import com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapPOI;
import com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapSettings;
import com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapSurfaceListener;
import com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapSurfaceView;
import com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewHolder;
import com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKPOICluster;
import com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKScreenPoint;
import com.skobbler.ngx.navigation.SKNavigationListener;
import com.skobbler.ngx.navigation.SKNavigationManager;
import com.skobbler.ngx.navigation.SKNavigationSettings;
import com.skobbler.ngx.navigation.SKNavigationState;
import com.skobbler.ngx.poitracker.SKDetectedPOI;
import com.skobbler.ngx.poitracker.SKPOITrackerListener;
import com.skobbler.ngx.poitracker.SKPOITrackerManager;
import com.skobbler.ngx.poitracker.SKTrackablePOI;
import com.skobbler.ngx.poitracker.SKTrackablePOIRule;
import com.skobbler.ngx.poitracker.SKTrackablePOIType;
import com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteInfo;
import com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteJsonAnswer;
import com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteListener;
import com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteManager;
import com.skobbler.ngx.routing.SKRouteSettings;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

import static com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapSettings.SKMapDisplayMode.MODE_2D;
import static com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapSettings.SKMapDisplayMode.MODE_3D;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SKMapSurfaceListener, SKRouteListener, SKNavigationListener, SKPOITrackerListener {

    public static final double SOURCE_LONGITUDE = 11.5;
    public static final double SOURCE_LATITUDE = 48.12;
    public static final double DEST_LONGITUDE = 11.5;
    public static final double DEST_LATITUDE = 51.12;

    private SKNavigationManager navigationManager;
    private HashMap<Integer, SKTrackablePOI> trackablePOIs;
    private SKPOITrackerManager poiTrackerManager;

    protected SKMapSurfaceView mapView;
    @Bind(R.id.view_group_map)
    protected SKMapViewHolder mapHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mapHolder.setMapSurfaceListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapHolder.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapHolder.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionPan() {}

    @Override
    public void onActionZoom() { }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(SKMapViewHolder skMapViewHolder) {
        mapView = mapHolder.getMapSurfaceView();
        mapView.centerMapOnPosition(new SKCoordinate(11.5, 48.12));
        launchRouteCalculation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapRegionChanged(SKCoordinateRegion skCoordinateRegion) {
        mapView.getMapSettings().setFollowerMode(SKMapSettings.SKMapFollowerMode.NONE);
        final SKCalloutView mapPopup = mapHolder.getCalloutView();
        mapPopup.setTitle("Fortsetzen").setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mapPopup.setViewColor(Color.argb(255, 200, 200, 255));
        mapPopup.setOnLeftImageClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Left image clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mapView.getMapSettings().setFollowerMode(SKMapSettings.SKMapFollowerMode.NAVIGATION);
                mapPopup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        mapPopup.showAtLocation(new SKCoordinate(23.56, 46.77), true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapRegionChangeStarted(SKCoordinateRegion skCoordinateRegion) {}
    @Override
    public void onMapRegionChangeEnded(SKCoordinateRegion skCoordinateRegion) {}
    @Override
    public void onDoubleTap(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {}
    @Override
    public void onSingleTap(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {}
    @Override
    public void onRotateMap() {}
    @Override
    public void onLongPress(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {}
    @Override
    public void onInternetConnectionNeeded() {}
    @Override
    public void onMapActionDown(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {}
    @Override
    public void onMapActionUp(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {}
    @Override
    public void onPOIClusterSelected(SKPOICluster skpoiCluster) {}
    @Override
    public void onMapPOISelected(SKMapPOI skMapPOI) {}
    @Override
    public void onAnnotationSelected(SKAnnotation skAnnotation) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCustomPOISelected(SKMapCustomPOI skMapCustomPOI) {}
    @Override
    public void onCompassSelected() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCurrentPositionSelected() {}
    @Override
    public void onObjectSelected(int i) {}
    @Override
    public void onInternationalisationCalled(int i) {}
    @Override
    public void onDebugInfo(double v, float v1, double v2) { }
    @Override
    public void onBoundingBoxImageRendered(int i) {}
    @Override
    public void onGLInitializationError(String s) {}
    private void launchRouteCalculation() {
        SKRouteSettings route = new SKRouteSettings();
        route.setStartCoordinate(new SKCoordinate(SOURCE_LONGITUDE, SOURCE_LATITUDE));
        route.setDestinationCoordinate(new SKCoordinate(DEST_LONGITUDE, DEST_LATITUDE));
        route.setNoOfRoutes(1);
        route.setRouteMode(SKRouteSettings.SKRouteMode.CAR_FASTEST);
        route.setRouteExposed(true);
        SKRouteManager.getInstance().setRouteListener(this);
        SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(route);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRouteCalculationCompleted(SKRouteInfo skRouteInfo) {}
    @Override
    public void onRouteCalculationFailed(SKRoutingErrorCode skRoutingErrorCode) {}
    @Override
    public void onAllRoutesCompleted() {
        SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings = new SKNavigationSettings();
        navigationSettings.setNavigationType(SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationType.SIMULATION);

        navigationManager = SKNavigationManager.getInstance();
        navigationManager.setMapView(mapView);
        navigationManager.setNavigationListener(this);
        navigationManager.startNavigation(navigationSettings);

        initTrackablePOIs();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        startPOITracking();
    }


    private void initTrackablePOIs() {
        Log.w(getClass().getName(), "initTrackablePOIs(): ");
        trackablePOIs = new HashMap<Integer, SKTrackablePOI>();
        initOnlySomePOIs();
        int i = 0;
        double longitude, latitude;
        for (double d = 0; d < 1; d+= 0.01) {
            longitude = SOURCE_LONGITUDE + d * (DEST_LONGITUDE - SOURCE_LONGITUDE);
            latitude = SOURCE_LATITUDE + d * (DEST_LATITUDE - SOURCE_LATITUDE);
            trackablePOIs.put(i, new SKTrackablePOI(i, 1, longitude, latitude, -1, "STREET_NAME " + i));
            SKAnnotation skAnnotation = new SKAnnotation(64000 + i);
            skAnnotation.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
            skAnnotation.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(longitude, latitude));
            mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);
            i++;
        }
    }

    private void initOnlySomePOIs() {
        double longitude, latitude;

        longitude = SOURCE_LONGITUDE + 0.001;
        latitude = SOURCE_LATITUDE + 0.001;
        trackablePOIs.put(101, new SKTrackablePOI(101, 1, longitude, latitude, -1, "STREET_NAME 101"));
        SKAnnotation skAnnotation1 = new SKAnnotation(101);
        skAnnotation1.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
        skAnnotation1.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(longitude, latitude));
        mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation1, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);

        longitude = SOURCE_LONGITUDE + 0.001;
        latitude = SOURCE_LATITUDE - 0.001;
        trackablePOIs.put(102, new SKTrackablePOI(102, 1, longitude, latitude, -1, "STREET_NAME 102"));
        SKAnnotation skAnnotation2 = new SKAnnotation(102);
        skAnnotation2.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
        skAnnotation2.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(longitude, latitude));
        mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation2, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);

        longitude = SOURCE_LONGITUDE - 0.001;
        latitude = SOURCE_LATITUDE + 0.001;
        trackablePOIs.put(103, new SKTrackablePOI(103, 1, longitude, latitude, -1, "STREET_NAME 103"));
        SKAnnotation skAnnotation3 = new SKAnnotation(103);
        skAnnotation3.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
        skAnnotation3.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(longitude, latitude));
        mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation3, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);

        longitude = SOURCE_LONGITUDE - 0.001;
        latitude = SOURCE_LATITUDE - 0.001;
        trackablePOIs.put(104, new SKTrackablePOI(104, 1, longitude, latitude, -1, "STREET_NAME 104"));
        SKAnnotation skAnnotation4 = new SKAnnotation(104);
        skAnnotation4.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
        skAnnotation4.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(longitude, latitude));
        mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation4, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);

        longitude = SOURCE_LONGITUDE + 0.002;
        latitude = SOURCE_LATITUDE + 0.002;
        trackablePOIs.put(105, new SKTrackablePOI(105, 105, longitude, latitude, -1, "STREET_NAME 105"));
        SKAnnotation skAnnotation5 = new SKAnnotation(105);
        skAnnotation5.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
        skAnnotation5.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(longitude, latitude));
        mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation5, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);

        longitude = SOURCE_LONGITUDE + 0.002;
        latitude = SOURCE_LATITUDE - 0.002;
        trackablePOIs.put(106, new SKTrackablePOI(106, 1, longitude, latitude, -1, "STREET_NAME 106"));
        SKAnnotation skAnnotation6 = new SKAnnotation(106);
        skAnnotation6.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
        skAnnotation6.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(longitude, latitude));
        mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation6, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);

        longitude = SOURCE_LONGITUDE - 0.002;
        latitude = SOURCE_LATITUDE + 0.002;
        trackablePOIs.put(107, new SKTrackablePOI(107, 1, longitude, latitude, -1, "STREET_NAME 107"));
        SKAnnotation skAnnotation7 = new SKAnnotation(107);
        skAnnotation7.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
        skAnnotation7.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(longitude, latitude));
        mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation7, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);

        longitude = SOURCE_LONGITUDE - 0.001;
        latitude = SOURCE_LATITUDE - 0.001;
        trackablePOIs.put(108, new SKTrackablePOI(108, 1, longitude, latitude, -1, "STREET_NAME 108"));
        SKAnnotation skAnnotation8 = new SKAnnotation(108);
        skAnnotation8.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
        skAnnotation8.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(longitude, latitude));
        mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation8, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);

        longitude = 9.767972;
        latitude = 52.378958;
        trackablePOIs.put(109, new SKTrackablePOI(109, 1, longitude, latitude, -1, "STREET_NAME 109"));
        SKAnnotation skAnnotation9 = new SKAnnotation(109);
        skAnnotation9.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
        skAnnotation9.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(longitude, latitude));
        mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation9, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);
    }

    private void startPOITracking() {
        SKTrackablePOIRule rule = new SKTrackablePOIRule();
        rule.setAerialDistance(5000); // this would be our main constraint, stating that all the POIs with 5000m, aerial distance should be detected
        rule.setNumberOfTurns(100); // this has to be increased – otherwise some points will be disconsidered
        rule.setRouteDistance(10000);//this has to be increased as the real road route will be longer than the aerial distance
        rule.setMinSpeedIgnoreDistanceAfterTurn(20); //decrease this to evaluate all candidates
        rule.setMaxDistanceAfterTurn(10000); //increase this to make sure we don't exclude any candidates
        rule.setEliminateIfUTurn(false); // setting this to true (default) excludes points that require us to make an U-turn to get to them
        rule.setPlayAudioWarning(false);
        poiTrackerManager = new SKPOITrackerManager(this);
        poiTrackerManager.startPOITrackerWithRadius(1500, 0.5);
        poiTrackerManager.setRuleForPOIType(SKTrackablePOIType.SPEEDCAM, rule);
    }
    @Override
    public void onServerLikeRouteCalculationCompleted(SKRouteJsonAnswer skRouteJsonAnswer) {}
    @Override
    public void onOnlineRouteComputationHanging(int i) {}
    @Override
    public void onDestinationReached() {}
    @Override
    public void onSignalNewAdviceWithInstruction(String s) {}
    @Override
    public void onSignalNewAdviceWithAudioFiles(String[] strings, boolean b) {}
    @Override
    public void onSpeedExceededWithAudioFiles(String[] strings, boolean b) {}
    @Override
    public void onSpeedExceededWithInstruction(String s, boolean b) {}
    @Override
    public void onUpdateNavigationState(SKNavigationState skNavigationState) {  Log.v(getClass().getName(), "onUpdateNavigationState: " + skNavigationState.toString());}
    @Override
    public void onReRoutingStarted() {}
    @Override
    public void onFreeDriveUpdated(String s, String s1, SKNavigationState.SKStreetType skStreetType, double v, double v1)  {}
    @Override
    public void onViaPointReached(int i) {}
    @Override
    public void onVisualAdviceChanged(boolean b, boolean b1, SKNavigationState skNavigationState) {}
    @Override
    public void onTunnelEvent(boolean b) {}
    @Override
    public void onFcdTripStarted(String s) {}

    @Override
    public void onUpdatePOIsInRadius(double latitude, double longitude, int radius) {
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "onUpdatePOIsInRadius(): ");
        // set the POIs to be tracked by the POI tracker
        for (SKTrackablePOI skTrackablePOI : trackablePOIs.values()) {
            Log.i(getClass().getName(), "onUpdatePOIsInRadius() skTrackablePOI: " + skTrackablePOI);
        }
        poiTrackerManager.setTrackedPOIs(SKTrackablePOIType.SPEEDCAM, new ArrayList<SKTrackablePOI>(trackablePOIs.values()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedPOIs(SKTrackablePOIType type, List<SKDetectedPOI> detectedPois) {
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "onReceivedPOIs() detectedPois.size(): " + detectedPois.size());
        if (detectedPois.size() == 1 && detectedPois.get(0).getPoiID() == -1) {
            return;
        }
        for (SKDetectedPOI skDetectedPOI : detectedPois) {
            Log.i(getClass().getName(), "onReceivedPOIs() skDetectedPOI: " + skDetectedPOI);
            SKAnnotation skAnnotation = new SKAnnotation(skDetectedPOI.getPoiID());
            skAnnotation.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_GREEN);
            skAnnotation.setLocation(trackablePOIs.get(skDetectedPOI.getPoiID()).getCoordinate());
            mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why the tracker isn't working. :(

Comment: Our dev team will look into it

Answer (score 0):

The rules are OK. 
You'll need to modify your logic to something similar to the demo project:

(the following code is to be added in the demo project, MapActivity.java, the `onAllRoutesCompleted` callback, the `currentMapOption == MapOption.POI_TRACKING` branch)

```
            poiTrackingManager.startPOITrackerWithRadius(10000, 0.5);
            // set warning rules for trackable POIs
          //  SKTrackablePOIType myType =SKTrackablePOIType.forInt(1000);
            SKTrackablePOIRule rule = new SKTrackablePOIRule();
            rule.setAerialDistance(5000); // this would be our main constraint, stating that all the POIs with 5000m, aerial distance should be detected
            rule.setNumberOfTurns(100); // this has to be increased – otherwise some points will be disconsidered
            rule.setRouteDistance(10000);//this has to be increased as the real road route will be longer than the aerial distance
            rule.setMinSpeedIgnoreDistanceAfterTurn(20); //decrease this to evaluate all candidates
            rule.setMaxDistanceAfterTurn(10000); //increase this to make sure we don't exclude any candidates
            rule.setEliminateIfUTurn(false); // setting this to true (default) excludes points that require us to make an U-turn to get to them
            rule.setPlayAudioWarning(false);
            poiTrackingManager.setRuleForPOIType(SKTrackablePOIType.SPEEDCAM, rule);                
            launchNavigation();
```

In onUpdatePOIsInRadius you have to make the "refreshed" POI list available to the tracker. This callback will be triggered by the tracker once the refreshMargin condition is reached.

```
@Override
    public void onUpdatePOIsInRadius(double latitude, double longitude, int radius) {

        // set the POIs to be tracked by the POI tracker
       // SKTrackablePOIType myType =SKTrackablePOIType.forInt(1000);
        poiTrackingManager.setTrackedPOIs(SKTrackablePOIType.SPEEDCAM,
                new ArrayList<SKTrackablePOI>(trackablePOIs.values()));
    }
```

In onReceivedPOIs you'll get information about the POIs that were detected:

```
public void onReceivedPOIs(SKTrackablePOIType type, List<SKDetectedPOI> detectedPois) {
 //add code here to handle the detected POIs

}
```

I've edited the vanilla demo project with the above code (with the default definition of points to track) and I get lots of notifications.

Depending on the "density" of your tracked POIs, you might want to reduce the refreshMargin (and trigger POI set updates more often) - i.e.         `poiTrackerManager.startPOITrackerWithRadius(5000, 0.1);`

Also see http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/detecting-tracking-pois-in-your-way/ for more insights into the POI tracking functionality

Comment: Thank You, Ando. The main difference between your and my code is that you launch the navigation after initializing the POI tracker. I did so and now in ``onUpdatePOIsInRadius()`` many tracked POIs are set. But the ``onReceivedPOs()`` method still doesn't track anything. Do you think it matters if I launch the navigation before or after setting um the POI tracker?

Comment: So the onReceivedPOIs is called, but detectedPois is empty?

Comment: That's right. But detectedPois is not completly empty. There is always one detected POI with id=-1. Maybe POI detection doesn't work in Navigation Simulation mode?

Comment: You will get a callback with a POI with id = -1 after you've just "passed" a tracked POI